# Question about linear mapping between vector spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

For the following three parts question:

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the collection of all intervals of the form $[\alpha, \infty)$ where $\alpha\geq 0$ is a real number.  Then for all $I_1$, $I_2$ in $\mathcal{I}$, we also have $I_1\cap I_2\in \mathcal{I}.$  Let $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I}):\{f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\mid I\in\mathcal{I}\}$.  We define the operations of pointwise addition and multiplication to be $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$, also $\mathcal{F}(V,W)$ maps vector space $V$ to vector space $W$ 
Let $f_0:[\alpha, \infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the zero function,

1. Is it true that $f_0+f=f$ for all $f\in \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I})$.

2. If $f_0+f=f$ for all $f\in \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I})$, is $f_0$ the only element of $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I})$ with this property?
3. Is it true that for each $f\in \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I})$, there is some $g\in \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I})$ such that $f+g=f_0$

I  would like to know if my answers are correct. For (1), I think the answer is a yes, because if $f$ is a zero map, then $f_0+f=0+f=f$ for any $f\in \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I})$

For (2), answer again is yes because of the reason stated in the answer in (1)

For (3), I think the answer is yes.  For any $f$ which is not the zero function , then $f+g=f_0=0$, hence the unique $g$ is the additive inverse of $f$, meaning $g=-f$.

If I am missing something in my answers or there are incorrections in any ways, can someone please point then out.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you define pointwise addition and scalar multiplication, but write the axioms for $f$ being a linear map. This is odd to me. Moreover you don’t take the domains into consideration.

Given $f:I_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: I_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ you will have to define $f+g: I_1 \cap I_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. now to your questions.

Let us write $0_\alpha$ for the zero function on the interval $[\alpha,\infty)$.

1) It holds that $0_0 + f=f$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I})$, which is **not** true for any $0_\alpha$, where $\alpha > 0$. (Recall that pointwise Addition is only defined on the intersection of domains!)

2) $0_0$ is the unique function with this property, since it has to be zero in any point where it is defined (assume otherwise and construct a counterexample) and it has to have maximal domain (see 1)

3) again, out of considerations of domains we can say that the only functions, which admit an additive inverse (adding up to $0_0$), are the ones with domain $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: I thought the zero function means the same as the zero map.  Is that correct. Zero function is $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$ or does it mean something different?

Comment: This is in some sense correct. The words function and map are used somewhat synonymously. However you have to be careful, on which set your zero map is defined. For two sets $X \neq Y$ the map $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in X$ is distinct from the map $g:Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g(y) = 0$ for all $y \in Y$, since they have different domains.

Comment: when i initially try to solve the question, i did not know the indivdual functions are defined over the intersection of the two domains $\mathcal{I}_1\cap \mathcal{I}_2$, even though that is the property defined for $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I})$. I just used $f:I\rightarrow R$. I also did not think that $[\alpha, \infty)$ would play much of a role in the answer.

Comment: But you can only define pointwise operations, when you have the points. So there is no other way. Did I help you or is there something left open for you?

Comment: First my apologies for the late response.  I am getting over a bad cold.  
I am still a bit confused over part 1 of the question.  I understand that if we have two functions $f$ and $g$, then $f+g\in I_1\cap I_2$, where $I_1=[\alpha_1, \infty)$, and $I_2=[\alpha_2, \infty)$ and $I_1\cap I_2 = max\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2\}$.  But for part 1 of the question, it seems that for $f_0 + f = f$, all it matters is the range of $f_0$, since $f_0 (x)=0$ for all $x\in [\alpha, \infty)$ and for all $\alpha \geq 0$, hence $f_0 (x) + f = 0 + f =f$

Comment: also i might have interpreted the notation for the functions $f\in \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I})$ incorrectly.  It states that $f_0$ is defined as $f_{0}:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Does the subscript $0$ for $f_0$ correspond to the value of $\alpha$ in the semi-open interval $[\alpha, \infty)$.

Comment: according to the text, $\mathcal{F}(X,W)$ is defiend as the collection of all functions $f:X\rightarrow W$ where $X$ and $W$ are arbitrary nonempty sets.  When $W$ is a vector space $\mathcal{K}$, the collection $\mathcal{F}(X,W)$ can be turned into a vector space over $\mathcal{K}$ in a natural way: if $f,$, $g$ are in $\mathcal{F}(X,W)$ and $\alpha\in \mathcal{K}$, defined addition and scalar multiplication by $(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(\alpha f)(x):=\alpha f(x)$. That is what the text was referring to as pointwise addition and multiplication.

Comment: No problem, hope you feel better. Before I give an answer: you have to be very careful with notation. $f+g \in I_1 \cap I_2$ makes no sense, $f+g: I_1 \cap I_2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ does. Likewise $I_1 \cap I_2 = [\max(\\alpha_1,\alpha_2),\infty)$ and not just $\{\max(...)\}$.

Comment: The definition of pointwise addition of your text is correct, but note that in your case we don’t just have one $X$, instead there is a plenthora of them, given by all the $I_\alpha$. Hence we have to be more careful when defining pointwise addition, which is what my answer is about. Your assumption that only the range being zero matters is wrong. For example let $f:\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb R$ evaluate to $0$ and $g:\mathbb N_0 \rightarrow \mathbb N_0$ map $n$ to $n$. Obviously $n+0=n$ for all $n$, but the definition of pointwise addition is given as $f+g(n) = f(n)+g(n)$, so what is $f(42)$ ...

Comment: ... supposed to mean? We can only plug in the value $0$ into $f$, so the only $n$, where pointwise addition is defined, is $\{0\}$. So by your reasoning $f+g$ should be $g:\mathbb N_0 \rightarrow \mathbb N_0$, but according to the definition of pointwise addition it can’t be anything else than $f:\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb N_0$. And the functions $f$ and $g$ are clearly distinct from each other, because they have **different domains**

Comment: Sorry I just noticed I initially wrote $f:\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb R$, but then switched to natural numbers for simplicity. Hence it should be $f:\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb N_0$

Comment: actually, I never got a precise definition of what pointwise operation means in mathematics.  The only other context i have seen the adjective pointwise is from convergence of sequence and series of functions. At that context, it was never explain why it is called "pointwise" until I looked up on wilkipedia.   Without looking at the precise wording of "pointwise" definition, my mental image of it is similar to coordinate-wise operation. Also, I think when the question ask about the zero function,...

Comment: ..I thought since a zero function is like a zero map where it sends everything in the domain to zero.  Hence I only have to care about the range of the function and did not know it is domain dependent.  I emailed the author about the confusion over this issue, and here is his reply: 

"If $h$ and $g$ are functions with domains $A$ and $B$, and if the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is not empty, then by the usual convention (which I should have stated explicitly), the domain of  h+g is the intersection of $A$ and $B$. I defined $f_0$ to have domain $[0,\infty)$ for the following reasons:...

Comment: ...If $f$ is any function with domain $[a, \infty)$ and $a\geq 0$, then the domain of $f_0+f$ is the intersection of $[0,\infty)$ and $[a, \infty)$, which is $[a,\infty)$. Thus, the domain of $f_0+f$ equals the domain of $f$. We need the domain of f_0+f to be equal to the domain of $f$, or else, the answer to part 1 would obviously be a "NO". (By definition of equality of two functions, a necessary condition for two functions to be  equal is that their domains must be equal).

Comment: ..Had we defined the domain of $f_0$ to be some thing like $[b, \infty)$ where $b>0$, then for any  function $h$ with domain $[b/2,\infty)$, it is impossible for $f_0+h$ to be equal to $f_0$ (because in this case, the domain of $f_0+h$ is $[b,\infty)$ whereas the domain of $h$ is strictly larger)...

Comment: ...The subscript $0$ in $f_0$ has no relationship with the domain of $f_0$. It was simply a coincidence. We could have denoted the zero function by $H$, without using any subscript.  If you pick a function in the collection $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{I})$ and you happen to label it as $f_k$, then all you know is that the domain of $f_k$ is some set of the form $[b,\infty)$ for SOME $b\geq 0$. You cannot assume that its domain must be $[k,\infty)$."

Comment: Right. His answer is precisely what I tried to communicate to you aswell.